# Oneboxing of deleted users' comments in chat results in empty links

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, chat, onebox

For the funs, I wanted to link to [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/52181/how-to-track-websites-that-have-been-visited/52593#comment293167_52593) in chat.

On-site, the user name is not clickable since the account has been deleted.

> [image]

In chat though, the username is linked to:

> [image]

The link is empty though, and as a consequence points to the chat room itself:

> [image]

Ideally, the username would not become linked in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed with extreme prejudice.

[dog pictures with HILARIOUS captions http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/advice-animals-memes-animal-memes-insanity-pup-try-fixing-that.png](http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/advice-animals-memes-animal-memes-insanity-pup-try-fixing-that.png)